# How to Trace JavaScript Dynamically Created Elements to Their Origins in Code?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, sapui5

Have a SAPUI5 application. Html view created by xml. JavaScript controllers. Some elements of this application, e.g. buttons are created somewhere dynamically within the controllers of the respective views. I.e. cannot use the id of an element to get it in the controller because the ids are dynamically created. Would like to get those dynamically created elements of the application to modify them, e.g. modify the buttons. What's the best way to trace a dynamically created element back to its code where it's created? E.g. how to trace a button back to it's origin in the JavaScript controller? It's a huge application and a view has multiple controller. I'm not just lazy.

[image]

Comment: you can't. There's no relationship between a finished element and the way it was created. It's either in the DOM or it's not, and that's all there is to it. It could have been written by hand, or created by server- or client-side code but there's no way for you to tell, unless the code that created it has added some custom attribute to indicate that. What you _could_ do is step through the code, or narrow it down to places which construct that type of element, or something.

Comment: that's a pitty. what do you understand by some custom attribute if i may ask?

Comment: I dunno, it's unlikely but maybe they could write `<a href="http://www.example.com" data-generatedBy="MyApplication">Link</a>`. Like I say, I've never seen it done, but if you wanted this kind of traceability in your code and you control the code which creates the elements, you could make it write them like that

Comment: unfortunately, just need to find those elements in the code. didn't wrote a line of code of this application. guess then i've no other choice than to skip through the code. anyway, thank you

Comment: Well if they are dynamically created you can try searching your source for `"new Button"` or `"new sap.m.Button"`. In the constructor of each button add a custom class or some other custom attribute until you find the constructor of your desired button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `render` function in the component's renderer class is what (eventually) creates the DOM element. You can inject a debugger statement into it like so:

```
let __buttonRender = sap.m.ButtonRenderer.render;

sap.m.ButtonRenderer.render = function() {
    let control = arguments[1];
    console.log('Creating button: ', control.sId);
    debugger;
    return __buttonRender.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

You can probably modify the control object based on the Id here. I'm not exactly sure what your end goal is here. The renderer is probably taking attributes and data from XML, so if you want to modify the buttons, I'd do it at the data source. The above could would allow you to hack the model before it reaches the DOM, but it's kinda nasty.